# c++ WINAPI call exported function via GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dllexport, getprocaddress

Im trying to call an exported function from a DLL by grabbing its function pointer through `GetProcAddress` but upon calling the function the application crashes.

I used dependencywalker to see if the exported functions have the correct name. The address returned from `GetProcAddress` is not null. I'm almost certain that it has something to do with the calling convention, i used both `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` but no success. However i do would like to use `GetProcAdress` instead of `__declspec(dllimport)`.

**DLL #1 (Caller)**

- Linked DLL#2.lib to this DLL

  ```
  typedef void(__stdcall *ptr_init)(DWORD size);

  ctx.hModule = LoadLibraryA("someDLL.dll");
  ptr_init init = (ptr_init)GetProcAddress(ctx.hModule, "init");

  if (init == NULL) {
      out = out + " | init function is null";
  } else {
      out = out + " | init function found!";//It is found
  }

  DWORD test = 10;
  (*init)(test);//<-- makes application crash
  ```

**DLL #2 (DLL containing exported function)**

```
//header.h
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void init(DWORD size);

//source.cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void init(DWORD size) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: You don't have the compiler to help you when you get it wrong.  Looks like you got it wrong, that doesn't look very __stdcall.  Otherwise no compelling reason to avoid using the debugger.

Comment: The function is cdecl. Why did you use stdcall. Can't you write init(test). Problem is likely in your DLL. Consider creating a MCVE.

Comment: *"However i do would like to use `GetProcAdress` instead of `__declspec(dllimport)`."* - Why would that be? If all you need is control over when, and how imports are resolved, you could use [delay-loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx), and handle import resolution in your code (see [Understanding the Helper Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be consistent. If you retrieve pointer as a pointer to `stdcall` function - it must be declared as `stdcall` in implementation:

```
//header.h
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall init(DWORD size);
```

Comment: `__stdcall` makes the application crash but removing all `__stdcall` works, why is that?

Comment: Because the function is declared in the DLL code as `__cdecl`.